# Best CFNetwork Wrapper tools in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, networking

In My Application, I need to Create Web Request and Response Methods. If Any Advanced Wrapper is there? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well It depends on you what to use on Networking.There are a lot of options

1. [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) : By apple itself
2. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) : Most preffered,My personal suggestion,Uses blocks
3. [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) ,Good but discontinued

Comment: What is the problem in ASIHttp?

Comment: @EverythingMaker : ASIHttp doesnt thave anything wrong,it is being not continued by devoloper and the latest one AFNetworking takes better advantage of blocks

Comment: It's no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below Two links.

http://afnetworking.com/

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

I hope its must use for your reference.